# referring steps from a different project in specflow not working

Tags: c#, .net, app-config, bdd, specflow

In App.config, declaring

```
<stepAssemblies>
    <stepAssembly assembly="MyAssembly" />
</stepAssemblies>
```

while trying to add some reusable steps from a different project in the same solution is not working.

What could be the possible reasons for it to not work?

Comment: What **exactly** do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: The Given condition is still purple..

Comment: @AnKumar: The intellisense has some problems with additional step assemblies. But it should work when you execute the tests.